# alias template is not a class template?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I am trying to write a type trait to detect if a type has a `T::type` of certain type. I am using [code from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30848101/4117728). For reference this is the part of the code I am using:

> ```
> // See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4502.pdf.
> template <typename...>
> using void_t = void;
>
> // Primary template handles all types not supporting the operation.
> template <typename, template <typename> class, typename = void_t<>>
> struct detect : std::false_type {};
>
> // Specialization recognizes/validates only types supporting the archetype.
> template <typename T, template <typename> class Op>
> struct detect<T, Op, void_t<Op<T>>> : std::true_type {};
> ```

I started simple with a trait to detect the `T::type` :

```
template <typename T>
using has_type_t = typename T::type;

template <typename T>
using has_type = detect<T, has_type_t>;
```

This works as expected, but when I ask for the actual type of `T::type` also I get errors that I do not understand:

```
template <typename X>
struct has_X_type_helper {
    template <typename T>
    using type = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v< typename T::type, X>,int>;
};

template <typename T,typename X>
using has_X_type = detect<T,has_X_type_helper<X>::type>;
```

GCC:

```
<source>:49:55: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for 'template<class, template<class> class<template-parameter-1-2>, class> struct detect'
   49 | using has_X_type = detect<T,has_X_type_helper<X>::type>;
      |                                                       ^
<source>:49:55: note:   expected a class template, got 'has_X_type_helper<X>::type'
```

and Clang is even more confusing for me

```
<source>:49:29: error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template
using has_X_type = detect<T,has_X_type_helper<X>::type>;
                            ^
```

Is `has_X_type_helper<X>::type` not a type alias template ? What is wrong in my code?

[@ godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4sWBAS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indicate that the nested thing is a template:

```
template <typename T, typename X>
using has_X_type = detect<T, has_X_type_helper<X>::template type>;
//                                               ~~~~~~~~~^
```

Comment: i think this is the new top in my list of most unintuitve syntax. Is it needed because `has_X_type_helper` is a template? or because `has_X_type_helper<X>::type` is a template? I still find it a bit confusing, because `has_X_type_helper<X>` is just a type and `has_X_type_helper<X>::type` is a template just as `has_type_t` is one

Comment: ah I think I got it. `has_X_type_helper` could have specializations so I need to assure the compiler that `type` is a template

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes, it's the same story as with `typename`. Otherwise, the compiler assumes it's a value like `std::is_const<T>::value`, hece it reports `'type/value mismatch'`