# Template template parameter and template alias: compiler bug?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, template-templates, template-aliases

I have got problem with the following representative sample code:

```
template<int I>
struct X {};

template<int I>
struct Y {};

template<int I>
struct XX: X<I> {};

template<int I>
struct YY: Y<I> {};

template<template<int> class TP>
struct traits;

template<>
struct traits<X> {
    template<int I>
    using Tpl=XX<I>;
};

template<>
struct traits<Y> {
    template<int I>
    using Tpl=YY<I>;
};

template<template<int> class TP>
struct Z {};

template<template<int> class TP>
struct W: Z<traits<TP>::Tpl> {};

int main() {
 
  Z<traits<X>::Tpl> zx;
  Z<traits<Y>::Tpl> zy;
  W<X> wx;
  W<Y> wy;

  return 1;
}
```

This code compiles fine with icc-19.0.0 (and seems to compile with msvc-19.24), but fails to compile with gcc-10.1, clang-10.0.0 and icc-18.0.0.

With gcc-10.1, the error message is:

```
<source>:32:28: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<template<int <anonymous> > class TP> struct Z'

   32 | struct W: Z<traits<TP>::Tpl> {};

      |                            ^

<source>:32:28: note:   expected a class template, got 'traits<TP>::Tpl'
```

Context: I have a template class `Z` which have a template template parameter. I would like to derive a class from it, `W`, which for the end user accept the same template template parameter as `Z` (`X` or `Y`), but dispatch them to internal classes `XX` and `YY` which modifies the behavior of `X` and `Y` by deriving from them.

Is this problem a compiler bug? If yes, is there some kind of workaround?

Many thanks!

Comment: very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62277828/alias-template-is-not-a-class-template

Comment: wasnt sure if it qualifies as duplicate, on a second thought it actually does...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that `Tpl` is a template:

```
template<template<int> class TP>
struct W: Z<traits<TP>::template Tpl> {};
                   // ^^
```

Afaik, nothing changed about that, I could be that some compilers are / have been more lax about it and let you get away without it.
The reason it is needed is similar to why `typename` is needed for types: There could be specializations of `traits` where `Tpl` is not a template, so you need to tell the compiler that it really is one.